# How to efficiently assign properties only to points in a sphere out from three dataframes containing properties in cartesian coordinates?

Tags: python, pandas, optimization, geometry-surface

My problem is the following. I created a dataframe with 20,000 points for x and density.
x varies from [-1,1].  This is representative not only of x but also of y and z.
The density at the sphere surface is what I want and that is the sum of the three density (interference).

I am doing this by brute force. Would there be a better way?  I ask because I will have to circularly shift the densities and get new interference patterns and do optimization to match the Cosmic Microwave Background. Because of the high resolution of the CMB, the number of points is large.

```
def createSphere(a1,a2,a3,dfX):
    dfX["xP"]= np.roll(dfX.x, a0)
    dfX["DensityX"]= np.roll(dfX.DensitySTD, a1)
    dfX["DensityY"]= np.roll(dfX.DensitySTD, a2)
    dfX["DensityZ"]= np.roll(dfX.DensitySTD, a3)
    dfY=dfX[dfX.x<=2]
    dfY.x=dfY.x-1
    dfsphere=pd.DataFrame(columns=["i", "j", "k","x","y","z", "density"])
    for ind,inda in enumerate(itertools.product(dfY.index,dfY.index,dfY.index)):
            if (dfY.iloc[inda[0]].x**2 +dfY.iloc[inda[1]].x**2 +dfY.iloc[inda[2]].x**2 -1)<=0.001:
                dens = dfY.iloc[inda[0]].DensityX +dfY.iloc[inda[1]].DensityY +dfY.iloc[inda[2]].DensityZ 
                dfsphere.loc[ind,"i"]=inda[0]
                dfsphere.loc[ind, "j"]=inda[1]
                dfsphere.loc[ind, "k"]=inda[2]
                dfsphere.loc[ind,"x"]=dfY.iloc[inda[0]].x
                dfsphere.loc[ind, "y"]=dfY.iloc[inda[1]].x
                dfsphere.loc[ind, "z"]=dfY.iloc[inda[2]].x
                dfsphere.loc[ind,"density"] = dens
    return dfY, dfsphere

dfY, dfsphere = createSphere(a1,a2,a3,dfX)de here
```

Comment: Python doesn't have dataframes. Please remember to use the [tag:pandas] tag if you're asking about Pandas.

Comment: Thank you.  I will remember it next time.  Later, I thought that this could be solved as a sphere illumination problem, but I am not sure how to write it down, if that is really possible.

Comment: I realized that I should had started the mapping from the sphere itself and not the other way around.  I will do that and post my new approach later.